# How to change bootstrap tabs in Angular 2

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have a template for a tab that I got from **bootsnip** without any js. My problem is how to change the tabs, When I click on a certain tab, it directs me to a different page.
Please look into my code.

```html
<div class="container">
  <h6 class="section-title h1">Tabs</h6>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <nav>
        <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
          <a
            class="nav-item nav-link active"
            id="nav-home-tab"
            data-toggle="tab"
            href="#nav-home"
            role="tab"
            aria-controls="nav-home"
            aria-selected="true"
            >Home</a
          >
          <a
            class="nav-item nav-link"
            id="nav-profile-tab"
            data-toggle="tab"
            href="#nav-profile"
            role="tab"
            aria-controls="nav-profile"
            aria-selected="false"
            >Profile</a
          >
          <a
            class="nav-item nav-link"
            id="nav-contact-tab"
            data-toggle="tab"
            href="#nav-contact"
            role="tab"
            aria-controls="nav-contact"
            aria-selected="false"
            >Contact</a
          >
          <a
            class="nav-item nav-link"
            id="nav-about-tab"
            data-toggle="tab"
            href="#nav-about"
            role="tab"
            aria-controls="nav-about"
            aria-selected="false"
            >About</a
          >
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="tab-content py-3 px-3 px-sm-0" id="nav-tabContent">
        <div
          class="tab-pane fade show active"
          id="nav-home"
          role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab"
        >
          Et et consectetur ipsum labore excepteur est proident excepteur ad
          velit occaecat qui minim occaecat veniam. Fugiat veniam incididunt
          anim aliqua enim pariatur veniam sunt est aute sit dolor anim. Velit
          non irure adipisicing aliqua ullamco irure incididunt irure non esse
          consectetur nostrud minim non minim occaecat. Amet duis do nisi duis
          veniam non est eiusmod tempor incididunt tempor dolor ipsum in qui
          sit. Exercitation mollit sit culpa nisi culpa non adipisicing
          reprehenderit do dolore. Duis reprehenderit occaecat anim ullamco ad
          duis occaecat ex.
        </div>
        <div
          class="tab-pane fade"
          id="nav-profile"
          role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab"
        >
          Et et consectetur ipsum labore excepteur est proident excepteur ad
          velit occaecat qui minim occaecat veniam. Fugiat veniam incididunt
          anim aliqua enim pariatur veniam sunt est aute sit dolor anim. Velit
          non irure adipisicing aliqua ullamco irure incididunt irure non esse
          consectetur nostrud minim non minim occaecat. Amet duis do nisi duis
          veniam non est eiusmod tempor incididunt tempor dolor ipsum in qui
          sit. Exercitation mollit sit culpa nisi culpa non adipisicing
          reprehenderit do dolore. Duis reprehenderit occaecat anim ullamco ad
          duis occaecat ex.
        </div>
        <div
          class="tab-pane fade"
          id="nav-contact"
          role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab"
        >
          Et et consectetur ipsum labore excepteur est proident excepteur ad
          velit occaecat qui minim occaecat veniam. Fugiat veniam incididunt
          anim aliqua enim pariatur veniam sunt est aute sit dolor anim. Velit
          non irure adipisicing aliqua ullamco irure incididunt irure non esse
          consectetur nostrud minim non minim occaecat. Amet duis do nisi duis
          veniam non est eiusmod tempor incididunt tempor dolor ipsum in qui
          sit. Exercitation mollit sit culpa nisi culpa non adipisicing
          reprehenderit do dolore. Duis reprehenderit occaecat anim ullamco ad
          duis occaecat ex.
        </div>
        <div
          class="tab-pane fade"
          id="nav-about"
          role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="nav-about-tab"
        >
          Et et consectetur ipsum labore excepteur est proident excepteur ad
          velit occaecat qui minim occaecat veniam. Fugiat veniam incididunt
          anim aliqua enim pariatur veniam sunt est aute sit dolor anim. Velit
          non irure adipisicing aliqua ullamco irure incididunt irure non esse
          consectetur nostrud minim non minim occaecat. Amet duis do nisi duis
          veniam non est eiusmod tempor incididunt tempor dolor ipsum in qui
          sit. Exercitation mollit sit culpa nisi culpa non adipisicing
          reprehenderit do dolore. Duis reprehenderit occaecat anim ullamco ad
          duis occaecat ex.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you add demo?

Comment: @AkilMakda Here Sir.. https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/1eOby

Comment: You need JS to change the tabs. Also there is no way this redirects you to a new page, only anchor links are used here. So you get redirected to the same page, just a different section.

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably just use ngif and ngclass if not router-outlet.

Comment: Please have a look at these bootstrap tabset https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabset/examples.